# What part do I need for my broken iPhone 3G?

Tags: iphone, screen

One morning my iPhone 3G just showed up with a gray screen. Everywhere I looked said that I need to replace the screen.
I bought an "iPhone 3G Screen + Digitizer" off the internet but it turns out this is NOT the part I need.
I have the technical ability to replace the screen...but I have no idea what part it is that I'm looking for.  Can anyone help me figure this one out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which part you need exactly, but one resource that has helped me repair my iPhone 3G is [iFixit.com](http://www.ifixit.com/). Especially their [iPhone 3G](http://www.ifixit.com/Device/iPhone_3G) page which lists many of the iPhone's [parts](http://www.ifixit.com/iPhone-Parts/iPhone-3G).

They even have a [Q&A section](http://www.ifixit.com/Answers/Device/iPhone+3G) specifically targeting iPhone 3G repair which you may find of use.